# findViewById() returning the same object regardless of argument

Tags: android, android-studio, findviewbyid

I have two EditText containers on my Login Activity with two different names. When I call them using findViewById() method, the first call returns one of EditText objects and the other returns null. when i switch the referance id and rerun the application build it assign the same EditText object to the variable as it did before changing the argument. No matter what I do the same outcome.

I have tried changing the Resource Id, I have tried a whole new layout file and nothing is working.

This is the part of the main activity.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        loginViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, new LoginViewModelFactory())
                .get(LoginViewModel.class);

        final EditText usernameEditText = findViewById(R.id.username_text);
        final EditText passwordEditText = findViewById(R.id.password_text);
        final Button loginButton = findViewById(R.id.login);
```

This is the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".ui.login.LoginActivity">

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/login_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"

        android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/username_text"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="48dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="@string/action_sign_in_short"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password_text"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/createAccount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:text="@string/create_account"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/login"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        />


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/password_text"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/password_text"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.3" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"

        android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

No matter what i pass as an argument to findViewById() the outcome is

```
usernameEditText = androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText{5bfb16 VFED..CL. ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f09010b app:id/username_text}
passwordEditText = null;
```

I have even tried switching the two arguments to check if there was just something wrong with my passwordEditText. The outcome was still the same

Comment: Hi, can you please include your layout file and the snippet of code relevant to the problem you are facing?

Comment: so i tried swithing the arguments on findViewById() for the EditTexts and no matter what i but in as an argument it returnd the exact same EditText and the second is always null

Comment: @TrevorMongomery You have called the password field "password_text" in the xml but "passwordInput" in the activity. If that fixes the issue, then I'd vote to close this question

Comment: So i onyl did that to check if it would change the object it returns

Comment: You updated it to be "password_text_text" that would also not work. Does it work when you `findViewById(R.id.password_text)`?

Comment: @NicRobertson I have tried using a few differnet editText ids to see if it changes the outcome andc nothing changes

Comment: @NicRobertson no whatever i pass to findViewById() it always returns the username_text EditText then null for the second even when i change what i pass as an argument

Comment: An expensive suggestion would be to use data binding. You wouldn't have to deal with any findViewById() drama.. But like i said, it's an expensive suggestion.

Comment: @TaslimOseni That would solve the problem but is a bit expensive for a login screen

Comment: @TrevorMongomery can you post the entire layout file? also can you explain why you are using the `ViewModelProviders` class? it appears to be deprecated

Comment: Hello Trevor, Are you try adding cast to EditText in findviewbyId?

Comment: I havent tried casting it as EditText but im not sure whats that would help. It retruns the right Object type.

Comment: @NicRobertson I used and old login from another app i worked on and havent changed the ViewModelProviders yet.

Comment: Are you sure the new version is installed on the emulator? I often see it say "rerun successful; no install needed" (especially when I only make XML changes). I recommend you try uninstalling the app from your device, rebuild, and run.

Comment: @AjahnCharles thats a great i dea ill try that

Comment: @AjahnCharles I tried uninstalling that app off of the emulator and it didnt help anything